# On PyCharm my left key and right key isn't responding

Tags: python, windows, pygame, pycharm

```
#enable pygame mode
import pygame
pygame.init()

#create screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900,600))

#Title + Logo
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")
icon = pygame.image.load("chicken.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

#Player icon
player_icon = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
playerX = 400
playerY = 500

def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(player_icon, (x, y))

#game loop
running = True
while running:

    # backround colour  RGB
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            #If key pressed check wether its right or left
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    print("key left pressed")
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    print("key right pressed")
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    print("key stroke has benn released")


    #Player change in coordinates
    playerX += 0
    playerY += 0

    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I have been learning about pygame and game programing using python during this quarantine. I have been doing this by watching a tutorial on youtube. Please don't downgrade me I have tried harder to make my question better last time it was my first question and got 2 downgrades. Thankyou for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It s a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). In your code the `pygame.KEYDOWN` event is only evaluated in case of  `event.type == pygame.QUIT`. "Move" the `pygame.KEYDOWN` event handling:

```py
running = True
while running:

    # backround colour  RGB
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        # <--| INDENTATION

        #If key pressed check wether its right or left
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                print("key left pressed")
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                print("key right pressed")
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                print("key stroke has benn released")
```

Comment: what do you mean with is a matter of indentation. Where?

Comment: @Arno.B Please read the complete answer ans see the comment `# <--|` in the middle of the code

Comment: Thank you so much. It was getting so frustrating.